# Wrong time in Docker container of Django app built by Jenkins

Tags: python, django, docker, jenkins

I am comparing two container times. One built on my local machine and the other is built on the Jenkins server.

I attached to both of them and tried these commands:

**First**: `date` function of the Linux. The same results:

```
Locally running container: Sat May 27 10:47:06 UTC 2017

Container running on Jenkins server: Sat May 27 10:47:28 UTC 2017
```

**Second**: `python` shell. The same results:

```
Locally running container: '2017-05-27 10:59:40.005836'

Container running on Jenkins server: '2017-05-27 10:59:35.567902'
```

**Third**: `datetime.now()` in Django shell (`./manage.py shell`). Different results:

```
Locally running container: '2017-05-27 06:01:52.547923'

Container running on Jenkins server: '2017-05-27 11:01:17.001070'
```

Locally running container is the correct one because in my Django app, I set the timezone to `America/Chicago` and at the time of this writing this is the correct time.

The one in Jenkins is wrong and looks as if ignoring the timezone set by Django.

I don't understand why. Thank you for any help

Comment: Try setting in Dockerfile: `ENV TZ=America/Chicago`

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was just to install `tzdata`. It turns out the base image did not have it.

This package provides time zone and daylight-saving time data.

So, just adding the following to the Dockerfile solved the issue:

```
RUN apt-get install tzdata
```